# httpd-mmn version conflict when installing php 7.2?

Tags: php, apache, mod-php

I am trying to install php 7.2 on centos 6, and it results in the following error. I followed the steps as explained in: [LINK](https://www.tecmint.com/install-php-7-in-centos-6/).

From other posts I understand it's probably because I build httpd 2.4 from source. But I can't find a good solution how to solve it. I cleaned the yum caches and updated yum, etc.. as found in other posts, but no luck. 
What is the correct way to solve this?

Should I build php 7.2 also from source?

```
Error: Package: php-7.2.3-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php72)
           Requires: httpd-mmn = 20051115
           Installed: httpd-2.4.12-1.x86_64 (installed)
               httpd-mmn = 20120211
           Available: httpd-2.2.15-59.el6.centos.x86_64 (base)
               httpd-mmn = 20051115
           Available: httpd-2.2.15-60.el6.centos.4.x86_64 (updates)
               httpd-mmn = 20051115
           Available: httpd-2.2.15-60.el6.centos.5.x86_64 (updates)
               httpd-mmn = 20051115
           Available: httpd-2.2.15-60.el6.centos.6.x86_64 (updates)
               httpd-mmn = 20051115  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem  You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles
--nodigest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mod_php in remi repository is always build against default httpd version in base repository (so version 2.2 in CentOS 6).

Don't know where your httpd 2.4 comes from, but you cannot use mod_php with it (and looks like an outdated version...).

BTW, I recommend to switch to FPM which is a much modern way to execute PHP scripts, and which is mandatory if you also need HTTP2.

See [PHP Configuration Tips](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/10/25/php-configuration-tips/)

If you really need httpd 2.4, you can also switch to CentOS 7

Comment: I build httpd 2.4 from source. I need httpd 2.4, and no, I can't switch to CentOS 7. Can't I just build php 7.2 from source?

Comment: "Can't I just build php 7.2 from source", yes you can, but good luck (especially on C6).

Comment: I just build it, worked out fine, just building it on the production server. Why good luck?

Comment: Because C6 is really old, and lot of libraries / tools are outdated and don't meet the minimal requirement of recent PHP versions.

Comment: BTW, if you like to waste your time building from sources, when binary packages exists, and use the old deprectated mod_php way...

Comment: Like I said, I have build it, very fast, no problems, and it's working fine with php-fpm..

Comment: So initial problem was trying to install mod_php... when you want to use php-fpm.... lol...

Comment: Yes true, you suggested phph-fpm and read about it and used it, all fine ;)